# 8086 assembly division

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I have this problem with the code below which converts number to ASCII 'number-text'. However the code seems to loop at the 'div' opcode

```
;Main Program
main:
    mov ax, 0x0000
    mov ds, ax ; setup data segment register
    mov si, GreetString ; setup data segment offset
    call print_string ; call print string procedure
    mov si, DataWord ; setup data segment offset
    mov bl, 0x000A ; base 10
    call format_string ; call format string procedure
    mov si, GreetString ; setup data segment offset
    call print_string ; call print string procedure
prevent_overflow:
    hlt ; halt the CPU
    jmp prevent_overflow

format_string:
mov ax, [ds:si] ; load register ax with data
xor cx, cx ; set counter to 0
mov si, GreetString ; set pointer to address of GreetString

.format_char:
div bl ; divides by register bl
add ah, 48 ; convert to ascii numeric
mov [ds:si], ah ; move ascii numeric to ds:si
inc cx ; increase counter
inc si ; increase si
xor ah, ah ; clear ah register
or ax, ax
jnz .format_char ; jump to format next char
ret
```

Any idea why does this happen? I say 'loop' because my CPU is at max-value and does not proceed with the opcodes after div

*Updated. Thanks newgre. Added main section to make it more readable (^.^)

Comment: What value does bl have? You never assign it explicitly.

Comment: yes sorry for that. i did assign it in the main section

mov bl, 0x000A ; base 10
call format_string ; call format string procedure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you get a division overflow exception because the quotient (in my example below it's 12345 div 10 = 1234 + remainder of 5) doesn't fit into the 8 bits of `al` (remember that `ah` is already used by the remainder?).

Every time either the quotient or the remainder doesn't fit into the destination register you get a division overflow exception. It's not only the division by 0 that causes it.

You want to do a 32/16=16:16 division instead of a 16/8=8:8 division.

Here's what works in DOS with my changes (marked as `;;;`):

```
; file: div2.asm
; compile as: nasm -f bin div2.asm -o div2.com
org 0x100 ;;;

;Main Program
main:
    mov ax, 0x0000
;    mov ds, ax ; setup data segment register ;;;
    mov si, GreetString ; setup data segment offset
    call print_string ; call print string procedure
    mov si, DataWord ; setup data segment offset
    mov bl, 0x000A ; base 10
    call format_string ; call format string procedure
    mov si, GreetString ; setup data segment offset
    call print_string ; call print string procedure

    ret ;;;

prevent_overflow:
    hlt ; halt the CPU
    jmp prevent_overflow

format_string:
mov ax, [ds:si] ; load register ax with data
xor cx, cx ; set counter to 0
mov si, GreetString ; set pointer to address of GreetString

.format_char:
; div bl ; divides by register bl ;;;
xor dx, dx ;;;
xor bh, bh ;;;
div bx ;;;

; add ah, 48 ; convert to ascii numeric ;;;
add dl, 48 ;;;

; mov [ds:si], ah ; move ascii numeric to ds:si ;;;
mov [ds:si], dl ; move ascii numeric to ds:si

inc cx ; increase counter
inc si ; increase si
; xor ah, ah ; clear ah register ;;;
or ax, ax
jnz .format_char ; jump to format next char

mov byte [ds:si], "$" ;;;
inc cx ; increase counter ;;;
inc si ; increase si ;;;

ret

print_string: ;;;
    pusha ;;;
    mov ah, 9 ;;;
    mov dx, si ;;;
    int 21h ;;;
    popa ;;;
    ret ;;;

DataWord dw 12345 ;;;
GreetString db "Hello World!", 13, 10, "$" ;;;
```

It prints:

```
Hello World!
54321
```

Comment: Thanks alot Alex =D
That certainly helped me! Thought i'm still quite confused why it resulted in a 'loop'?

Comment: If the default division exception handler (in the BIOS or DOS) simply returns back (with IRET), you get a loop: DIV->exception handler->DIV->exception handler->DIV->... The handler can't do anything more reasonable because it doesn't "know" where this instruction is (in what program or part of the system software) and what should the appropriate action in every case be. It's the best it can do. You can, however, redefine the handler and put in it logic appropriate for your program.

Comment: any advice or reference material on how to redefine the handler. is it just a struct?

Comment: It's a routine, pretty much like an interrupt service routine. It preserves all the registers it modifies, does its work, restores the registers and then returns with IRET. Read the Intel/AMD CPU manuals. See the sections about interrupt and exception handling and instructions `INT` and `IRET`.

Comment: thanks alot :D
Will read up about them. Hopefully i understand the documentations :D